# Tinker with laravel 8, cannot get the Relatioship

Tags: php, namespaces, relationship, laravel-8, tinker

i just created users * stories tables, and model , define relationship as shown below

**In User Model**

```
public function stories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Story::class);
}
```

**In Story Model**

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(App\User::class);
    }
```

**In tinker**

```
$user1=App\Models\User::find(1)
=> App\Models\User {#3356
     id: 1,
     name: "user1",
     email: "user1@localhost.com",
     email_verified_at: null,
     created_at: "2020-12-25 19:48:58",
     updated_at: "2020-12-25 19:48:58",
```

**But when i try to get all stories belong to user 1**

```
$user1->stories
```

***PHP Error:  Class "App\Story" not found in C:\xampp\laravel\storify\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasRelationships.php on line 745***

Answer (score 0):

It looks you are using wrong namespaces. Model files are located probably in `\App\Models` namespace (`app\Models` directory), so relationships should look like this:

**In User Model**

```
public function stories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Story::class);
}
```

**In Story Model**

```
public function user()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\User::class);
}
```

Comment: That's only if he's working with Laravel 8, where Model files are located in `app\Models`.

Comment: @FerToasted But it's tagged as Laravel 8 and in tinker console there is `$user1=App\Models\User::find(1)`

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you are accessing right to `Story.php` model

```
use App\Models\Story;
```